# C# Regex help (very quick answer)

Tags: c#, regex

I have the follow code:

```
string DB1 = DB1 = Regex.Match(contents, @"DB1=(?<DB1>[^\r\n]+)").Groups["DB1"].Value;
```

The code reads a file and looks for the following line:

DB1=Database\ABSER\ABSER

how can i modify the code that i have to exclude the 2nd \ABSER

I want my code to read only Database\ABSER , so essentially cut off the 2nd ABSER.  I also need to kill this like at the \r\n.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: what's the idea of "(very quick answer)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string DB1 = DB1 = Regex.Match(contents, @"DB1=(?<DB1>.*)\\.*").Groups["DB1"].Value;
```

try that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB1=(?<dbname>.*(?=\\))
```

This just uses a positive look ahead, its extremely brittle, and only addresses the 2nd sub-directory. A trailing slash on the second ABSER and an additional directory will break it.